# conflict between datepicker and jstree or multipul

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

i use datepicker in my page

datepicker that i used work with jquery 1.6.2 and jquery UI 1.8.14

then i use jstree that work with 1.9.0 or greater

and Multiple Select with at least 1.7.0 jquery

i load these js files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jq162 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.42.custom.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="js/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc2.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-timepicker-addon2.js"></script>
<link href="js/multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="js/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/themes/style.min.css" />
```

now i use this

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      jq162(function() {
        //----------------------------------
        jq162('#datepicker12from').datepicker({
          onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            jq162('#datepicker12to').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new JalaliDate(inst['selectedYear'], inst['selectedMonth'], inst['selectedDay']));
          }
      });
      jq162('#datepicker12to').datepicker();
      jq162('#datepicker').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

but also with this codes datepicker don't work

what can i do for this problem?

please help me if you can, i really need solve this program

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution here is to use the newer jQuery library, as the `DatePicker` would still work fine.

But...

There's a work around based on what you've tried using `.noConflict()`:

**HTML**

```
<-- Leave the jsTree library out of here -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="js/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.42.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc2.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-timepicker-addon2.js"></script>
<link href="js/multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/themes/style.min.css" />
```

**jQuery (Javascript)**

```
var jq162 = jQuery.noConflict(true);

// For debugging.
// You can see which version is loaded where.
console.log(jq162.fn.jquery);
console.log($.fn.jquery);

jq162(function () {
    jq162('#datepicker12from').datepicker();
});

$(function () {
    // Load the jsTree script library here.
    $.getScript('js/jstree.min.js', function () {
        // When it's done loading, create your jsTree stuff.
        $('#jstree1').jstree();
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c6bmadgL/10/)